# Display a Message Box over a Full Screen DirectX application

Tags: software-engineering, windows, directx

In our custom assertion handler, I'd like to display a message box asking to see whether or not this failure can be ignored.  However, when our DirectX game is full screen, I can't get the MessageBox function to display above the full screen.

Note: The first parameter to MessageBox is the the HWND used to create the device, and it still does not work.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you very well may be out of luck - (although there's a MessageBoxOptions that allows you to specify ServiceNotification, which might do the right thing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions.aspx)

Typically I write my own message rendering at that point (to make sure you can use the assert anywhere, on xbox, whatever).

Comment: Closest I could get is specifying MB_SETFOREGROUND, which works 50% of the time for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a WPF GUI instead (start with a prototype).
That should fix your problem.
(Render to a full screen WPF's DirectX surface and not directly to screen.)

Comment: Why is this voted down!? I have done this before and it DOES work.

Comment: WPF requires creating a managed stack.  In this case, I needed a pure Win32 / DirectX solution.

Comment: Well, state that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was able to tell last time we tried this, it isn't possible.