# How do I render my own DirectX Stuff to a full screen WPF's DirectX surface?

Tags: gui, directx, wpf

Basically Danny Varod seems to know as he posted it as an answer to this question:

[Display a Message Box over a Full Screen DirectX application](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/892/display-a-message-box-over-a-full-screen-directx-application)

I think, theoretically this might work, but I have no idea how to actually do it. Since I'm also not allowed to post a comment under his comment nor am I allwoed to ask on meta about how to contact another user, I ask this as a normal question here:

How do I render my own DirectX Stuff to a full screen WPF's DirectX surface?

For starters, I have no idea how to get the DirectX surface from a WPF window. If I had it, what do I have to take care of that the WPF rendering doesn't screw up my own rending or vice-versa?

Comment: Next time add a comment with an "@" sign before my name like so @DannyVarod for me to get an alert :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what he means is to host your DirectX surface in a full screen WPF application using the [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx) class.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could approach this, and I outlined them in [a response to a similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/can-a-standalone-wpf-application-create-an-interface-that-looks-like-a-flash-inte/3048#3048).